# Welche Verben stehen mit der Präposition "unter"?

Tags: verb, preposition

Zum Beispiel "leiden unter". Welche noch?

Comment: Die Frage (und damit auch die mögliche Antwort) leidet darunter, dass die Präposition *unter* weniger mit dem jeweiligen Verb zu tun hat als mehr mit dem Gegenstand, unter dem dann irgend was geschieht. Sucht man Verben mit *unter*, kommen zwar lauter schöne Wendungen heraus (jemanden unter den Tisch saufen; das ist unter aller Sau; unter den Sternen schlafen; unter die Räder kommen), aber das hat alles wenig mit den Verben zu tun; es sind halt ganze Ausdrücke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`<Verb>` unter" wird oft benutzt, um eine Beziehung zwischen dem nachfolgenden Substantiv und dem vorhergehenden Verb bzw. der dadurch beschriebenen Tätigkeit herzustellen.

Beispiel:

> Ich leide unter heftigen Kopfschmerzen.

--> das "Leiden" wird durch die heftigen Kopfschmerzen verursacht.[11]

> Die Einwohner Nordkoreas leben unter Kim-Jong-Un.

--> Das Leben der Nordkoreaner wird durch Kim-Jong-Un beeinflusst.[5]

> Die Angestellten einer Kleiderfabrik in Taiwan arbeiten unter heftigen Zeitdruck.

--> Die Arbeit wird massiv durch den Zeitdruck beeinflusst.[10]

Siehe auch: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unter_darunter_abwaerts_tiefer
Die Angaben in [eckigen Klammern] geben an, welche Nummer die entsprechende Bedeutung auf der verlinkten Duden.de-Seite hat.

Auf der Seite sind auch eine Vielzahl an Beispielen, mit welchen Verben "unter" benutzt werden kann.